# NSRangePointer error Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, nsattributedstring

This is what I am trying to achieve:

```
var range : NSRange? = NSMakeRange(0, (attributedString?.length)!)
attributedString?.attribute(NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: "OpenSans-Regular"), at: 1, effectiveRange: &range)
```

In second line, I receive a compile time error:

> Argument labels '(NSFontAttributeName:, at:, effectiveRange:)' do not match any available overloads

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need:

```
var range = NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedString?.length)
let font = attributedString?.attribute(NSFontAttributeName, at: 1, effectiveRange: &range)
```

The 1st parameter is just the attribute you wish to check for. You don't pass in a specific font. This method will tell you want font is found at the specified location.

Comment: How to add this attribute. Can't find an overload function for NSAttributedString which accepts just attribute

Comment: See my comment on your other question. You are using the wrong method to add an attribute.

Comment: How to add font in documentAttributes ?

Comment: Personally, I hate apple docs. They are never easy to understand and come without an example. If you understood them, please add one here.

Comment: Look at the list of methods available for `NSMutableAttributedString`. BTW-  you should close this question since I answered your original question. If you have a new question about adding attributes to an attributed string you should post a new question specific to that need.

Comment: I tried going through the doc before putting my comment. Didn't help.

Comment: As I said, you are now asking a completely different question than the one you posted here. You should close this one and post a new one specific to adding attributes.

Comment: Why not. Let me post another question. But for a user with such a reputation like yours it should not be hard to post a comment for some related query. For my next question, I better get a satisfying answer :) Looking forward.

Comment: I've already told you where to look. The list of methods shown in the docs for NSMutableAttributedString show a very obvious method for adding an attribute. Don't be afraid of the docs. Once you see the method you can easily search on its use here or through Google.